# Three boys, two systems, one PlayStation Plus account

Tags: playstation-plus

They all play on both systems at different times, but for some reason it is locking two of my kids out of all games.

I need all three kids to have access to all games on both systems at anytime. Why is this not working?

If I need to pay for another PlayStation Plus sub I will be very upset. I just bought them another PlayStation so they could all play together.

Comment: You're saying they play at different times, but then you contradict yourself by saying all kids need to have access at anytime. If someone is playing the owned games on one system, the other won't have access to them. If you use the same account on both systems, if one system logs in, the other will log out.

Comment: You can't log into two playstations with the same account and expect them both to be logged in at the same time. It doesn't work that way. You need two copies of the same game on two different accounts in order  for them to play simultaneously.. Otherwise, people can just open one account, purchase a game and share the account with 100 friends. It's like saying you have only one copy of a movie dvd, but you want two different players to be able to play the same disc at the same time without illegally copying the disc. That's just daft.

Comment: @deutschZuid Not all games use discs, do they?

Comment: @forest Not all, many are purchasable through the PS store. If you purchase there, the games are tied to the account and can be downlaoded on any system. Yet I believe you can only play on 1 system at a time

Answer (score 3):

As been stated before, you are not able to use the same account on multiple systems simultaniously. As soon as you log in on another system, the other will log out, because each account has an ID and that ID can only be online once. Else you can't who actually is using the account.

If you want them all to play together you have 2 options.

1. Pay for multiple PS-plus accounts as well as the games. (This is the only way they can all play online)
2. Find a game which supports multiple players on 1 console. I can't tell you any new games which support this (split-screen), but on PS2 there was Need for Speed and FIFA if I remember correctly.

For your information, pretty much any system (PC, XBox, PS) only allow every account to be logged in once. Don't get your hopes up and try to get around this. Unless you violate the ToS there is no way you can achieve what you want to.

Answer (score 1):

it wouldn't be a problem to play games that are offline like a single players game as long as they are on a disk not downloaded . however when both playstations want to go to an online game one of them will be locked out because psplus is for 1 machine at a time.